# Oracle database: ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column

Tags: java, spring-boot, oracle11g, spring-data-jpa

I used Long as my id in Oracle database. 
I see: 'ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column', when I try to save by Spring Data 'save' function.

I don't understand what the problem is. I've read that I should use CLOB instead of Long but I can't understand what CLOB is and how to use it.
Or maybe something else is the problem.
Fragments of my code:

Model:

```
@Entity
public class Picture {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "PICT_SEQ")
  @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "picture_seq", allocationSize = 5, name = "PICT_SEQ")
  private Long id;

  private String name;

  private String author;

  @Column(name="CREATED_DATE")
  @Convert(converter = LocalDateAttributeConverter.class)
  private LocalDate createdDate;

  private String content;

  // getXXX, setXXX...
}
```

Repository:

```
public interface PictureRepository extends CrudRepository<Picture,Long>{

  public List<Picture> findAll();

  public void delete(Picture pic);

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public Picture save(Picture pic);
}
```

Service layer:

```
@Service
public class PictureService {

  @Autowired
  private PictureRepository pictureRepo;

  public Picture savePicture(Picture p) {
      return pictureRepo.save(p);
  }

  //...
}
```

Controller fragment:

```
@RestController
public class PictureController {

  @Autowired
  private PictureService pictureService;

  @PostMapping(value="/send")
  public ResponseEntity<?> sendPictureToDatabase(@RequestBody Picture picture) throws IOException {

    pictureService.savePicture(picture); //here is the problem
    AjaxResponseBody result = new AjaxResponseBody();
    result.setMsg("success");
    result.setResult(pictureService.getAllPictures());
    return ResponseEntity.ok(result);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> I used Long as my id in Oracle database.

You have not to.

The [Oracle `LONG Datatype`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT1831)  is really not designed for to represent numeric types :

> Columns defined as LONG can store variable-length character data
>   containing up to 2 gigabytes of information. LONG data is text data
>   that is to be appropriately converted when moving among different
>   systems.

Instead, this id  :

```
@Id
private Long id;
```

should be mapped to a `NUMBER` type in oracle.

You could specify `NUMBER(19)` to be able to represent the Java `Long` range values which the max value contains `19` digits (`9223372036854775807`).

Comment: Ok, I understand.
Is there a possibility to do mapping at the model-level?

Comment: The entity cannot change this information store as table metadata. Can't you change the table ? Is it already used in production ?

Comment: I've wanted to do auto generated table by annotations, as I've done this with MySQL. This is my first app with Oracle and I'm a little surprised. Do I need to create table only manualy (with Oracle) because of different types? Can't Hibernate do this automatically?